# (React JS) problem with pushing elements into an array inside useEffect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push

Hi I'm new to programming in React JS and currently facing trouble about it.
its about pushing elements into array

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

import 'firebase/database';
import firebase from 'firebase';

import RenderTweet from './RenderTweet';
import RenderReply from './RenderReply';

export default function HomeTweet() {

    const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([])
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser')));
    const [tweetList, setTweetList] = useState([])
    const sortTweetsByTime = (tweets) => {

        tweets.sort(function compare(a, b) {
            var temp1 = new Date(a.date)
            var temp2 = new Date(b.date)
            return temp2 - temp1
        })

        return tweets;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let temp = []
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + authUser.uid + '/following').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(element => {
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + element.key + '/tweets').once('value').then(function (tweets) {
                    tweets.forEach(tweet => {
                        temp.push({
                            "ref": tweet.ref,
                            "date": tweet.val().date
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + authUser.uid + '/tweets').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(tweet => {
                temp.push({
                    "ref": tweet.ref,
                    "date": tweet.val().date
                })
            })

        })
        setTweets(temp)

        console.log(temp) //first log
        console.log(temp[0]) //second log
        // tweets.forEach(tweet => {
        //     temp2.push(
        //         <RenderTweet tweetRef={tweet.ref} />
        //     )

        // })
        // setTweetList(temp2)

    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid" >
            {/* {tweetList} */}


        </div>
    )
}
```

in first log, it prints out `temp` array with successfully pushed elements. (length: 4)
but in second log, it prints out `undefined`

[log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZURGI.png)

can someone help find out whats happening inside this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a duplicate of two issues.

your array is empty and `temp[0]` is undefined because react useState is not synchronous, and updates do not take effect until the next time your function component is evaluated:

[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

your first console.log shows data because you, a human, did not inspect the value in the console until your function component was re-evaluated and the useState has taken effect:

[Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: thanks for answering my problem:) Actually I also thought that first issue you mentioned can be a problem. but didn't know about second issue.